# Regular Expression for ASP.NET ID Using Javascript

Tags: asp.net, javascript, regex

I am trying to extract the word "need" from this string.

```
ctl00_ctl00_ContentMainContainer_ContentColumn1__needDont_Panel1
```

I have tried `[__]([.]?=Dont)`

This is using javascript .match()

I have even tried to use http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ but just can't solve this one. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will accomplish what you're looking for:

```
__(.*)(?=Dont)
```

You seem to be mixing up what a [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) - square brackets `[]` - does, instead you should be using regular brackets `()`.

In your regex `[__]` will only match a single underscore `_` and `[.]` will match a single period.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Unfortunately your regex returned an array of two values "__need" and "need"

Comment: Javascript doesnt supports lookbehinds i guess, so this is the best method here. And it works! I just have to access result[1] of that array. Thanks again

Answer (score 2):

```
(?<=__)\w+(?=Dont)
```

Matches all alpha-numbers between __ and Dont

**Edit**

Sorry, I havent noticed word JavaScript. It does not support lookbehind, so `__(\w+)(?=Dont)` can be used there.
If Regex should match even when nothing comes between __ and Dont use "\w*" instead of "\w+". Be careful with ".*" because dot matches almost all characters, do you allow spaces in ID?

I haven't noticed

Comment: No... there wont be a case where there are spaces. Your answer is also a very good answer because this regex produces the result I want, just not in javascript. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Your error is writing `[__]` instead of `__` (without the braces). `[__]` matches only a single underscore, so it will match `_ctl00_ContentMainContainer_ContentColumn1__need`.

[.] is also wrong. You should use something like: [^_]+ (anything except underscore).